# Google Play Store Pre-registration sign up showing zero even though people have pre-registered my app

Tags: android, google-play

So I have uploaded a **game app** on the **google play store** and currently, it's up for **pre-registration**. The problem is, even though I have ensured that quite a number of people have pre-registered but the play console dashboard is not updating and it's showing **zero**. I couldn't find any proper answer to this question. Can anyone kindly tell me why this might be happening and when it'll be updated?

[Pre-registration Date] [1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJRGA.png

Comment: From my experience: it usually takes 2 to 3 days for these numbers to update.

Comment: Can you add screenshots and dates to your question? By dates I mean when you started pre-registration, as it takes a few days for play console to update the data

Comment: Sure! @user14678216 My game went for pre-registration on June 01, it's already been 7 days. And I've added the screenshots as well. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: same problem with me.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem so I asked google support and I got this reply.

> Thanks for contacting the Google Play Developer Support team.

> I understand that you have concerns regarding your app's statistics for pre-registration users.
> Unfortunately, If pre-registration sign-ups have a low number of users, Google Play Console won't display pre-registration sign-up data. For privacy reasons, Google doesn't display pre-registration sign-up data when there are a low number of users. But rest assured, once you've reach or surpassed the threshold you will see the stats for your pre-registration

**1 Week Later:**

Now my registration crossed 50 and reached around 100. It started showing a 50 sign-up count in the play console. Maybe we have to cross 50 to show numbers, and it takes 3 to 4 days to update the last number.

Comment: I got over 2000 verified signups and mine is still showing 0 signups after 24hours.

Comment: It takes 3 to 4 days to update the number.